# Add route to action with string parameter, so all unknown requests go to this action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need to add route that will accept something like this `https://www.my.domain/someRandomAlphanumericString`

If received string is not valid, I`ll just redirect to index.

I understand that I need to add this route as a last one.

If I put this route as first - it works, but in this case it catches all routes:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "StringRoute",
            "{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "View" },
            new { id = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" }
            );
```

Comment: I'd say this needs to be the _first_ route, not the last.

Comment: @Andrei V if it will be first, it will catch all requests what is for other routes ass well.

Comment: Yup, that's right. I would suggest taking a look at [route constraints](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs).

Comment: I can only guess to move this route to the very end of your own custom routes but before the default MVC route (if you still keep it). We need to see the whole routing method in order to decide exact order of routes for you.

Comment: @WeTTTT Only other route I have is the default one

Comment: Ok, so in this case it just pretend the /home and /index to bring up the home page if you put the custom route first. you just need to either add this 2 route manually before the StringRoute, or fix your regex to make sure they exclude "home" and "index". Am I understanding it right?